# How Can I create Columns in AgGrid with for ? Angular2

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am trying create columns in AgGrid the way dinamic because I don't say he structure JSON. I have problems with the `'for'`

html

```
<ag-grid-angular #agGrid style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" id="myGrid" class="ag-theme-balham" [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

Component.ts

```
  private gridApi;
  private gridColumnApi;
  public gridOptions;
  public columnDefs;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) {}



  private createColumns(data) {
    return [{
                   I TRY...
          }]; 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{};
  }

  onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;

    this.http.get(this.config.getUrl('projectunits')).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      params.api.setRowData(data);
       this.columnDefs = this.createColumns(data);

    });
    params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
  }
```

I try :

```
return [{
     data.Results.array.forEach(element => {
    console.log(element);
     });
 }];
```

This say that : `data.` It's hope ":"

I also try:

```
 return [{
      for (i = 0; i < data.Results.length; i++) {
            console.log(data[i]);
    }
  }
```

This say "arithmetic operator should be any o number "

I have problems with for , I tried 4 , 5 different things...

My intention or idea is :

```
private createColumns(data) {
    return [{
            for (i = 0; i < data.Results.length; i++) {
             headerName: data[i] ,
             field: data[i],
             }
          } ]; //End header agrid
  }
```

Because I don't know the estructure the Json :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
private createColumns(data) {
    const columns: { [fieldName: string]: ColDef } = {};
    data.Results.forEach(colData => {
        columns[colData.id] = {
            headerName: colData.header,
            field: coldata.field
        }
    })
    return columns;
}
```

Comment: Error compiler : " Cannot find name ColDef " , Thanks for your help.

Comment: That is an interface from AgGrid. `import {ColDef} from 'ag-grid';`

Comment: I use import { GridOptions } from 'ag-grid';  Can I use two ?

Comment: My partner say that I can join directly el Json to columDefs, but He doesn't do, so I don't need use foreach, It is true ???

Comment: You can also do `data.Results.map`. For performance it doesn't really matter. We are talking about a 10-iteration-loop here. Do not over-optimize, do what is more readable for you